# Extract Images from an Excel Document

Tags: image, excel

I am doing some data mapping from an .xls excel document, and I am trying to write a quick script to pull images out excel document.

What is the quickest, simplest way to do this programatically?

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 and I would prefer to user python if possible.

Answer (score 8):

a XLSX file is a compressed file.

```
$ unzip file.xlsx
```

in `xl/media/` are all pictures.  This is not true for older .XLS files, but you can convert them to XLSX with a modern version of MS Office.

If you don't have MS Office, you can do the same thing with LibreOffice.  [Convert the file to .ods and then open it as a zip file](https://askubuntu.com/a/60534/5032) and it will be in the `Pictures` folder.

Answer (score 4):

I hate to answer my own question, but the best method I found only required two commands at the command line (assuming you have the right software installed).

First, use unoconv to convert the .xls to .pdf:

http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/

On Ubuntu 10.10 command line:

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv
unoconv -f pdf file.xls
```

Then extract the images from the pdf using pdfimages (which seems to come bundled with Ubuntu):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdfimages

Back on the command line:

```
pdfimages file.pdf fileimage
```

And done! All of the images in the .xls are now in separate files in the directory. This could be done very easily on most Linux systems using your language of choice. In python, for example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['unoconv','-f','pdf','file.xls'])
subprocess.call(['pdfimages','file.pdf','fileimage'])
```

I would love to hear a simpler solution if somebody has one.